# Showing that $G$ contains a path such that it remains connected after removing the path.

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem from Bollobas's book.

> Let $G$  be a connected graph with minimal degree $\delta(G) = k$ where $k \geq1$. Show that $G$ contains a path $(x_1,\ldots ,x_k)$ such that $G-\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ is also connected.

So far what I have from the hint is the following :

Let $x_1\ldots x_l$ where $l \geq k+1$ be a longest path. Suppose the contrary, that $G- \{x_1, \ldots ,x_k \}$ is disconnected and let $y_0 y_1 \ldots y_m$ be a longest path in a component $C$ not containing $x_{k+1}$. Then $d_{C}(y_0) \leq m$ but $y_0$ cannot be joined to $k-m$ vertices $x_1, \ldots, x_k$

Then how do we proceed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91507/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-showing-that-g-contains-a-path-such-that-i).

Answer (score 2):

I'll slightly reword the solution.

The key idea is that we can remove $\{x_1,\dots x_k\}=X$ where $x_1,\dots , x_l$ is a path of maximum length.

We proceed by contradiction:

Assume $G-X$ has at least two connected components. Let $C$ be one that does not contain $x_{k+1},\dots,x_l$.

We are going to build a path of length larger than $l$, which is a contradiction.

To do this we take a vertex $z$ in $C$ that is connected to the maximum number of vertices in $X$ (notice that it is at least one because $G$ is connected) and we take a path of maximum length $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_m$ in $C$ that ends in $z$.

Notice that all neighbours of $y_1$ must be in $y_2,\dots, y_m$ and so $y_0$ has at least $k-(m-1)$ neighbours in $X$, it follows that $z$ also has at least $k-(m-1)$ neighbours in $X$.

We donote the first such neighbour by $x_n$ and we look at the path $x_n,x_{n+1},\dots,x_k$. This path has at least $k-m+1$ elements.

So now we are going to consider a new path that is gonna be super long ! Are you ready? It is the following:

$y_1,y_2,\dots,y_m, x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_l$

How many elements are here?

The first chunk has $m$ elements, the second chunk has at least $k-m+1$ elements and the last chunk has $l-k$ elements.

This means that it has at least $l+1$ elements. This my dear friends constitutes a contradiction.

Comment: Why are all neighbours of $z$ in $y_1,\ldots, y_m$ or $X$? If $z$ has a neighbor in $C$ not in $y_1,\ldots, y_m$ there is indeed a longer path containing $z$ but $z$ won't be the endpoint anymore.

Comment: because  otherwise the path is not of maximum length

Comment: I think I see what you are doing here. But your answer isn't entirely correct as written. a) If you insist that the path be of maximum length in $C$ and ending at $z$ then you cannot ensure that all neighbours of $z$ are either in that path or in $X$. If $z$ has a neighbour in $C$ but not in the path, then you do get a longer path, but it doesn't end at $z$ anymore

Comment: However, if you pick a vertex $z$ that has $k-m >0$ neighbours in $X$ and no other vertex in $C$ has more neighbours in $X$ than $z$ does then there is indeed a path of length $m+1$ in $C$ ending at $z$.

Comment: Meanwhile in your proof, b)  you also need to be careful *how* you pick $z$ in the first place. In particular you need the assumption that $z$ has at least as many neighbors in $X$, as any other vertex in $C$ has in $X$. Otherwise your claim that there is a path $P$ in $C$ ending in $z$ that has $m$ vertices where $m$ is such that $z$ has $k-m$ vertices in $X$, is not guaranteed to hold. What if $z$ has only 1 neighbor in $X$ and $k-1$ neighbors in $C$, while every one of $z$'s $k-1$ neighbors in $C$ each in turn have $k-1$ neighbors in $X$?

Comment: Hello Mike, good points, I will fix it.

Comment: Cool Many Thanks @Jorge !

Comment: It should be ok now

Comment: Well, almost. The idea is this: That $z$ ($=y_0$?) has $k-m$ neighbours in $X$ and no vertex has more neighbours in $X$ than $z$ does, implies that every vertex in $C$ has at least $m$ neighbors in $C$ [due to minimum degree bound of $k$]. This implies that for every vertex $z'$ in $C$ (and in particular, $z'=z$) there is a path in $C$ with one endpoint $z'$ that has $m+1$ vertices.

Comment: That is all you need, the minimum number $m$ of neighbors that in $C$ that a vertex in $C$ has, gives you the path w the desired endpoint $z$ and the desired length $m+1$.

Comment: [In general, a graph $H$ with minimum degree $\ge L$ has, for every vertex $y \in H$ a path with $L+1$ vertices with endpoint $y$.] So here take $H$ to be the induced subgraph of $G$ on $C$; this has minimum degree at least $m$.

Comment: $z$ is $y_m{}{}{}$, while $y_0$ is the other endpoint, and $y_0$  must indeed have all neighbours in $X$ or in $y_2,\dots,y_m$ by maximality of the path.

Comment: Thanks I see it now. I did upvote your answer btw, that was a challenging question!

Comment: Thanks, I also upvoted your question by the way! Yeah it was a tough one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P= x_1 x_2,\ldots x_k \ldots x_l$ be a longest path in $G$ [note that there is such a path $P$ with $l \ge k+1$ vertices in $G$]. Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be the two components of $G \setminus \{x_1,x_2 \ldots, x_k\}$ [i.e., remove from $G$ the first $k$ vertices of $P$ and assume that $G$ is disconnected with at least two components $C_1$ and $C_2$]. As $x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_l$ form a path we may assume  $x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_l$ are in the same component so let us write wlog $x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_l \in C_2$.

Now, let us write $X=\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}$. Now if there is a vertex $y \in C_1$ adjacent to all $k$ vertices then the path $P' = yx_1x_2 \ldots x_l$ is longer than $P$, so there cannot be such a $y$. So let $m$ be the maximum number of vertices in $X$ that a vertex $y \in C_1$ is adjacent to in $G$. Then $m <k$, and as each vertex in $C_1$ has degree at least $k$ in $G$ [because $G$ has minimum degree $k$] and is adjacent to only vertices in $C_1$ or $X$, it follows that

1. There must be at least $k-m+1$ vertices in $C_1$ and furthermore every vertex in $C_1$ is adjacent to at least $k-m$ other vertices in $C_1$ [so that each vertex $y \in C_1$ can have degree at least $k$].
2. As every vertex in $C_1$ has at least $k-m$ neighbors in $C_1$, every vertex $y \in C_1$ is the endpoint of a path $P_y \subset C_1$ with at least $k-m+1$ vertices.
3. Letting $y$ be a vertex adjacent to precisely $m$ other vertices in $X$. Then letting $j$ be the lowest integer such that $y$ is adjacent to $x_j$, it follows that $|\{x_j, x_{j+1},\ldots , x_k\}| \ge m$, and in particular, that $x_jx_{j+1}\ldots x_k$ is a path with at least $m$ vertices, and that $x_jx_{j+1} \ldots x_kx_{k+1} \ldots x_l$ is a path with at least $m + (l-k)$ vertices.
4. So let $y$ and $j$ be as in 3. and let $P_y = y_1y_2 \ldots y_{k-m}y$ be a path in $C_1$ with $k-m+1$ vertices ending at $y$, as guaranteed by 2. Then by 3. the path $P_y \cup x_j x_{j+1} \ldots x_k$ $=y_1y_2\ldots y_{k-m}yx_j \ldots x_k$ is indeed a path and has at least $k-m+1$ $+ m$ $=k+1$ vertices.
5. Thus also from 3. the following holds:  $P_y \cup x_jx_{j+1} \ldots x_k x_{k+1} \ldots x_l$ 
   $=y_1y_2\ldots y_{k-m}yx_j \ldots x_kx_{k+1} \ldots x_l$ is a path with at least $(k-m+1) + (m + l-k)$ $l+1$ vertices. Which is a contradiction.

Thus letting $X=\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}$ be the first $k$ vertices of a longest path in $G$, it follows that $G \setminus X$ cannot have two components after all, and so $G \setminus X$ is connected.

---

A question was asked whether the vertices of the path with $k$ vertices were removed or the edges of the path. It doesn't matter as far as we are concerned the result holds either way. Note that $G \setminus X$ has one component, and as every vertex in $G$ has degree $k$, every vertex in $X$ is adjacent to at least one vertex in $G \setminus X$. So if one takes the graph $G \setminus X$ [which is one connected] and adds back each vertex $x$ in $X$ and the edges in $G$ between $x$ and $G \setminus X$ [but none of the edges between the vertices in $X$] then the resulting graph is connected too.